# converting jsp statement into html

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html> 
<head>  
<script>  
var request;  
function sendInfo()  
{  

var url="unlike.jsp";  

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){  
request=new XMLHttpRequest();  
}  
else if(window.ActiveXObject){  
request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
}  

try{  
request.onreadystatechange=getInfo;  
request.open("GET",url,true);  
request.send();  
}catch(e){alert("Unable to connect to server");}  
}  

function getInfo(){  
if(request.readyState==4){  
var val=request.responseText;  
document.getElementById('amit').innerHTML=val;  
}  
}  

</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<% try{  
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/facebook","root","sesame");  
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from likes ");  

    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
    while(rs.next()){ 

     out.println("<A HREF=\"unlike.jsp\">unlike</A id="amit"> "+rs.getInt(1)); 
    out.println("people liked this &#9787;");   

    }  
    con.close();  
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }  %>
</body>  
</html>
```

here i am developing a small "like button" like facebook using ajax and jsp, my problem is i am not able to understand how to write this out.print ---

```
 out.println("<A HREF=\"unlike.jsp\" id="link" onclick="return doalert()>unlike</A> "+rs.getInt(1));
```

with an id and an onClick function so that when user clicks is i should able to call the unlike.jsp and like.jsp respectively and hide this out.print as required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well try to change it like this, escape the quotes mark in the id and put it in the `<a>` tag because it's a bad parctice to put it in the closing tag:

```
out.println("<A HREF=\"unlike.jsp\" id=\"amit\" onclick=\"return doalert()\">unlike</A> "+rs.getInt(1)); 
out.println("people liked this &#9787;");
```

It works fine for me, I think that should do it.